# Envelope field is null in SOAPMessage object

Tags: java, soap, saaj

I'm trying to invoke some WS. I have server and client on my local machine. I'm 100% sure about content of message and it comes from server to client with no changes. Problem is that the client creates not correct `SOAPMessage` object which have envelope field under soapPart equals to null.

Client side code:

```
SOAPMessage responseMsg = conn.call(msg, urlEndpoint);
```

Server side code:

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = sp.getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader hdr = envelope.getHeader();
SOAPBody bdy = envelope.getBody();
bdy.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("response", "soa", "http://www.sbg.com"));

return msg;
```

Id debug window I see the following:

1) Server side debug window

[image: server side debug window]

2) Client side debug window

[image: Client side debug window]

I'm using SAAJ for communication and JDK 1.6.

Can anybody assist with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you responsible for both (client and server)? What is the message that the client sends?

In my experience, it helps to use a tool like SoapUI to test the message:

http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: Message is primitive. 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <soa:response _ctxID="cid=xref_members,cn=admin" status="Ok" xmlns:soa="http://www.sbg.com">
   <response_code>0000</response_code>
  </soa:response>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Main problem is that client creates SOAPMessage which does not contain envelope field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
    sm.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
    sm.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

    SOAPPart sp = sm.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope se = sp.getEnvelope();
    se.setEncodingStyle("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
    se.setAttribute("xmlns:SOAP-ENC", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
    se.setAttribute("xmlns:soa", "http://www.sbg.com");

    SOAPBody sb = sm.getSOAPBody();
    SOAPBodyElement el = sb.addBodyElement(new QName("http://www.sbg.com", "response", "soa"));
    el.setAttribute("_ctxID", "cid=xref_members,cn=admin");
    el.setAttribute("status", "OK");
    SOAPElement in = el.addChildElement("response_code");
    in.setValue("0000");
    sm.writeTo(System.out);
```

Comment: Envelope still equals to null. Seems to be MessageFactory issue... As it works fine in JDK 1.4 with external SAAJ lib. But in JDK1.6 it does not.

Comment: @user1818109 are you sure? Try to copy-paste my code in unit test and run it. I test it with Oracle JDK 1.6 with build-in WS support and it work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm sure. I saved SOAPMessage to ByteArray and then tried to restore it using the same MessageFactory on server side and it had envelope = null. `SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        sm.writeTo(bos);
        
        SOAPMessage sm2 = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(sm.getMimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));`

Comment: my congratulations. You can post it as an answer and assept it.

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance but I don't think this can be an answer. Problem still exists. And I don't understand why it is not working fine.

Comment: uh, my bad. a lack of sleep :) I thought you have found a cause of error.

Comment: I solved the problem. The issue was in xalan.jar I was using some ancient version of it. Now it's working fine. Thanks for assistance.